# Why hostname ip is different with my server ip?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ip

When I want to connect to my server *(using PuTTY)*, I have to enter this ip:

```
195.201.<n>.<n>
```

And the result of `cat /etc/hosts` is:

```
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
172.31.<n>.<n>  Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal
```

My question is, what's this ip `172.31.<n>.<n>`?

---

**Note1:** that `<n>` is a number, I didn't write it because of some security reasons.

**Note2:** `Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal` is what I see in the command line interface:

```
root@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal /path #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is on a Class B [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) behind a NAT router.

- `195.201.<n>.<n>` is the public (WAN) address
- `172.31.<n>.<n>` is the private (LAN) address

Comment: Oh, so is `172.31.<n>.<n>` my local ip server kinda?

Comment: It's not the local ip "server". It's your local area network ip hence LAN. You talk with your machines that are behind your router that connects the world (wide area network WAN) to your machines. That's why you need to talk with your router which has a WAN IP to be able to communicate to your local machines which have only an LAN ip. While NAT'ing is used to make it possible. I hope you get the general idea behind it.

Answer (score 1):

`hosts` file work the other way around when you input 
`Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal` 
it will redirect you to the ip in front of it in your case `172.31.<n>.<n>`.  So for example you can put this `195.201.<n>.<n> myserver` in your host file and when you try to connect to myserver it will connect you to `195.201.<n>.<n>`.

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor explanation, if you want i can elaborate

Comment: Don't say so, your answer contains a good point and that's why I give it an upvote. Also I got my answer, thank you.